# XCode IOS project not linking to Expo files

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on an Expo app that needs native functionality, so I am running expo run:ios. Everytime I run this however, it gives me an error saying this:

❌  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
┌─ Symbol: _AVMetadataObjectTypeCodabarCode
└─ Referenced from: l001 in EXBarCodeScanner(EXBarCodeScanner.o)

❌  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I try removing the expo-barcode-scanner library, the project builds and runs, but in expo it says "expo-asset could not be found within the project." Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can fix it is to update your Xcode to 13.3

Here's the xcode 13.3 image information: [Apple Website](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/#image--macos-monterey-123-xcode-133--alias--latest)

You can use the "image" property in your build profile.